# Magento 2 fail during installation

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

Mysql went down during Magento 2 installation on localhost and put site to maintenance mode without finalising installation.

Answer (score 1):

Quick 3 steps solutions:

1. Remove `var/.maintenance.flag` file
2. Run (in project root using terminal) `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. Run `php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='adminuser' --admin-password='adminpassword' --admin-firstname='Name' --admin-lastname='Surname' --admin-email='admin@email.com'`